# How to split a numpy array with different array lengths (unequal array lengths)

Tags: python, numpy

Given an example array (or list), is there a way to split the array into different lengths?
Here is desired input & output such that:

```
import numpy as np

# Input array
data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])

# Desired output splited arrays
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])]
```

I want to get the corresponding output, but it doesn't work, so I ask a question.

Comment: What is the logic to split? How could it generalize?

Comment: I checked that numpy `split` can only be divided into arrays with the same size, so I left a question wondering if there is a way to divide it into arrays of different lengths. I didn't know how @mozway responded. I will check that method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what you want exactly, but assuming you want 8 items for the first list, use [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
data = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])

out = np.array_split(data, [8])
```

output:

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]),
 array([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17])]
```

To be more generic, you can use a list of sizes and process it with [`numpy.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
sizes = np.array([4,5,1,3])
out = np.array_split(data, np.cumsum(sizes))
```

output:

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 3]),           # 4 items
 array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]),        # 5 items
 array([9]),                    # 1 item
 array([10, 11, 12]),           # 3 items
 array([13, 14, 15, 16, 17])]   # remaining items
```